# Simple Javascript issue

Tags: javascript

I want select all the elements with the `id` named singleFeed1 to singleFeed10;

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var post=document.getElementById('singleFeed'+i);
    post.style.color='blue';

    if (i==4){
        post.style.color='red';
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work.

my html

```
<li id=singleFeed1>aaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
<li id=singleFeed2>vvvvvvvvvvvv</li>
<li id=singleFeed3>dddddddddddd</li>
<li id=singleFeed4>aqqqqqqqqq</li>
<li id=singleFeed5>aaaaaddddaa</li>
......
......
​
```

Anyone has better solutions? Thanks.

Comment: The first thing to notice is that you have a serious syntax error, where `if (i=4)` should actually be `if (i === 4)`

Comment: @elclanrs whoops, you caught me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    var post=document.getElementById('singleFeed'+i);
    post.style.color='blue';

    if (i==4){ // you need two equal signs
        post.style.color='red';
    }
}
```

Next time check the console (i.e. firebug) and you will find these kind of errors on your own.

Comment: Start i from 1 till 10 (<=) and you should be all right with your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i=1;i<=10;i++){
    var post=document.getElementById('singleFeed'+i);
    post.style.color='blue';

    if (i===4){
        post.style.color='red';
    }
}
```

In your original code you try to get 0-9 instead of 1-10.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, @Chris has the right answer. However, I would do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<li id=singleFeed1 class="singleFeed">aaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
<li id=singleFeed2 class="singleFeed">vvvvvvvvvvvv</li>
<li id=singleFeed3 class="singleFeed">dddddddddddd</li>
<li id=singleFeed4 class="singleFeed">aqqqqqqqqq</li>
<li id=singleFeed5 class="singleFeed">aaaaaddddaa</li>
```

**Javascript**

```
var posts=document.getElementsByClassName('singleFeed');
for(var i=0;i<posts.length;i++){
    posts[i].style.color='blue';
    if(i==4){
        posts[i].style.color='red';
    }
}
```